# c++ segfault and pointers confusion (I have the feeling I'm missing something terribly obvious)

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, cout

I'm a python programmer new to C++.  Currently getting a segfault when trying to play around with pointers.  Can someone explain this behavior?  I suspect there's something significant about `cout` that I'm not understanding.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int var; // declaration
    cout << "var declared" << endl;
    cout << "var             : " <<  var << endl;
    cout << "&var            : " << &var << endl;

    var = 10; // initialization
    cout << "\nvar initialized" << endl;
    cout << "var             : " <<  var << endl;
    cout << "&var            : " << &var << endl;

    int* ptr; // declaration
    cout << "\nptr declared" << endl;
    cout << "ptr             : " <<  ptr << endl;
    cout << "*ptr            : " << *ptr << endl;
    cout << "&ptr            : " << &ptr << endl;

    ptr = &var; // initialization
    cout << "\nptr initialized : " << endl;
    cout << "ptr             : " <<  ptr << endl;
    cout << "*ptr            : " << *ptr << endl;
    cout << "&ptr            : " << &ptr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

using this compiler command

```sh
g++ --std=c++14 main.cpp -o main_exec;
```

This code produces the following output

```sh
var declared
var             : 0
&var            : 0x7fff55724478

var initialized
var             : 10
&var            : 0x7fff55724478

ptr declared
ptr             : 0x0
[1]    82727 segmentation fault  ./main_exec
```

This code obviously compiles but produces a segfault at runtime.

Things I've tried
I've tried combinations of commenting out the lines that include `*ptr` and the lines that include `&ptr`, short story is some combinations produce no segfault.  It seems that I can use `*ptr` 1 time and not in combination with `&ptr`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `cout`. You are trying to access value pointed to by `ptr` when `ptr` points to nothing (because it's not initialized). That's Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen Is using `int* ptr = new int;` to set aside an ints worth of memory a legitimate way around this or does that somehow miss the point?  Is there some reason not to always do this or at least do this by default?

Comment: `new` allocates memory on the heap and you are responsible to `delete` it after you are done using it. In modern C++ you generally want to avoid `new` (and raw pointers in general). If there is no good reason to use it, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: `var = 10; // initialization` no it's not, it's assignment. `ptr = &var; // initialization` no it's not, it's assignment. The difference between initialization and assignment is what you're missing.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Good, thanks for clarifying that as well.  I was thinking I was missing something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a pointer to an integer, but not initialized or assigned it with any pointer (i.e. to memory address of an integer variable).

```
int* ptr; // declaration
```

The line above says, **ptr** is a pointer (that would point to memory address of an integer variable). In your case it just says it is a pointer, what it does point is not defined.

When you hit this line,

```
cout << "*ptr            : " << *ptr << endl;
```

Here ***ptr** means, get the value at address (the address that actually would store the value) and is being pointed by **ptr**. However **ptr** points to nothing. So you're trying to access memory in a way that is not permitted which leads to the segmentation fault.

Just remember that pointers are variable that as their values store memory address of another variable.

```
int *ptr; // would store memory address of an integer type variable.
int a = 5; // would store an integer variable.
ptr = &a; // Here &a gets the address of variable a and stores in *ptr
cout<<*ptr // Here *ptr gets the value of variable whose memory address is pointed to by *ptr.
```

**Edit**

To answer the question if **int * ptr = new int;** is valid.

Yes it will reserve you a memory location and allows you to later store values on that location later, as shown in code below,

```
int* ptr = new int;  // gets memory address and assigns to *ptr
*ptr = 5; // assigns value 5 to the memory being pointed by *ptr
cout<<*ptr; // output 5
```

However you're supposed to not do this unless you've a particular need.

- Variables reserve you memory, and give you a friendly variable name of your choice.
- Anything you create with **new** is not deleted automatically, as suggested in comment section.
- Variables, in contrast to this, are deleted automatically when they get out of scope (block, function, loop, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  I'll vote up when I have enough "reputation" to do so.  That is obvious given your explanation.

I assumed that by virtue of declaring `int* ptr;` the behavior would be to set aside the appropriate memory.  Is it the case that NO memory is allocated in this case?

I was able to "avoid the error" by alocating an int's worth of memory with
`int* ptr = new int;`

Comment: Is using `int* ptr = new int;` a legitimate way around this?  Is there some reason not to always do this or at least do this by default?

Comment: @CWW updated answer, last section is about your question regarding using of new.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  That's clearer, I still have a lot to learn about pointers but I think this get's me to the point where I can start managing them well enough to get by for now.